# certificate enrollment on android

Tags: android

Does Jelly bean have support for certificate enrollment with certificate authorities for VPN etc? I know we can sideload certificates or download them and there are APIs for the certificate store etc. But is there support in the OS to request certificates from a CA over-the-air and hence, perform the entire certificate enrollment process via a protocol like SCEP?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Stock Android doesn't currently support certificate enrollment protocols. If you wanted to implement one you might want to have it run as a system app, because that is the only way to silently install certificates.